# Windows 2008 SP1 cannot make outbound connection

Tags: windows-server-2008, weblogic

I have a server that stops making outbound connection after some time. It is hosting various weblogic 9.2.0 domains, and restarting one particular server solves the problem, until next time. At first I suspected the server had exhausted its ephemeral tcp ports like described here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend.aspx. However netstat doesn't confirm my diagnosis, can I trust netstat or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "outbound connection"?  Is it failing to serve requested pages?

Comment: Why would the server be making outbound connections? The server is a web server, right? If so it shouldn't be initiating any outbound connections and shouldn't be using any ephemeral ports in it's duties as a web server.

Comment: Pages are served ok however it won't reach the database server for instance

Comment: It's also making web service calls

Comment: Have you checked the event logs on the web server and the database server? How do you become aware of the problem, an error in the client browser? If so, what's the error?

Comment: Some events with eventid 4227 but not around the times we have the problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a connection leak - You'll have to make sure that you're not running file descriptors.

Is there a firewall between the server and it's destination? There could also be a TTL defined on the server where it drops pooled connections after the pre-determined interval.

Comment: No firewall between servers, they're on the same lan